# How to Switch/Change Front and back Vuforia AR Camera using a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing an AR mobile app using Unity.

For that I have added a Vuforia AR Camera, it works fine with my Laptop cam, and it shows a 3D model on an image target.

My quastion is how can I switch between front cam and back cam on Android device using a simple button?

I have tried this code example to switch between the Laptop cam and an external webcam :

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using Vuforia;

 public class SwitchCamera : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private bool cameraMode = false;

     public void OnCameraChangeMode()
     {
         CameraDevice.CameraDirection currentDir = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraDirection();
         if (!cameraMode)
         {
             RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_FRONT);
             Debug.Log("Back Camera");
         }
         else
         {
             RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_BACK);
             Debug.Log("Front Camera");
         }
     }

     private void RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection newDir)
     {
         CameraDevice.Instance.Stop();
         CameraDevice.Instance.Deinit();
         CameraDevice.Instance.Init(newDir);
         CameraDevice.Instance.Start();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Montacer,
               You just forgot to change the cameramode value.

```
     CameraDevice.CameraDirection currentDir = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraDirection();
     if (!cameraMode)
     {
         RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_FRONT);
         cameramode = true;
         Debug.Log("Back Camera");
     }
     else
     {
         RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_BACK);
         cameramode = false;
         Debug.Log("Front Camera");
     }
```

other than that everything looks great.hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

just as update: Front camera was removed from Vuforia. https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Release_Notes/Vuforia-SDK-Release-Notes.html
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity/front-camera-deprecation

> Front camera support has been removed. You can now only access the back camera (CameraDevice::init() now does not take any parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code and it works perfectly.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class Cameraa : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool on = true;

    public void Switch()
    {
        on = !on;
        if (on)
        {
            CameraDevice.Instance.Stop();
            CameraDevice.Instance.Deinit();
            TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Stop();

            CameraDevice.Instance.Init(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_BACK);
            CameraDevice.Instance.Start();
            TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Start();

        }
        else if (!on)
        {
            CameraDevice.Instance.Stop();
            CameraDevice.Instance.Deinit();

            TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Stop();
            CameraDevice.Instance.Init(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_FRONT);

            CameraDevice.Instance.Start();
            TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and work fine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using TBEasyWebCam;


public class ARManager : MonoBehaviour
{
#if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS) && !UNITY_EDITOR
    bool isTorchOn = false;
#endif

    public void toggleTorch()
    {
#if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS) && !UNITY_EDITOR
        if (EasyWebCam.isActive) {
            if (isTorchOn) {
                //torchImage.sprite = torchOffSprite;
                EasyWebCam.setTorchMode (TBEasyWebCam.Setting.TorchMode.Off);
            } else {
                //torchImage.sprite = torchOnSprite;
                EasyWebCam.setTorchMode (TBEasyWebCam.Setting.TorchMode.On);
            }
            isTorchOn = !isTorchOn;
        }
#endif
    }

}
```